# Replacement not working in external JS file

Tags: javascript, html

I have my script file "js.js" referenced in my body after h1 and after p. The external javascript is to replace the text but it is not working. The code I have in html is:

```
<h1 id="header">Example Header</h1>
<script src="js.js></script>


var NewHeader = "New Header Text";
document.getElementByID("header").innerHTML = NewHeader;
```

Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: You're missing a closing quote on `js.js`. Also, have you looked at the console log?

Comment: `getElementById` not `getElementByID`. JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Comment: After fixing the getElementById issue it is still not working. The missing closing quote was just an error copying the code over

Answer (score 0):

just use script tag before the closing tag of body `</body>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1 id="header">Example header</h1>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

or if you want to use script tag in head tag then just
use `async` attribute of script tag so script will be fetched in parallel to parsing and evaluated as soon as it is available.
**Example :** `<script async src="js.js"></script>`